# How to ssh to a server using another server with key from the second server?

Tags: ssh, proxy

How to configure ssh to imitate this:

```
ssh server1-user-name@server1.net -i /path/to/.ssh/server-1-ssh-key -t ssh server2-user-name@10.0.0.10 -i /home/server1-user-name/.ssh/server2-ssh-key
```

When I execute

```
ssh server2
```

Explanation:

- I'm login to server1.net with a key from my local machine (`/path/to/.ssh/server-1-ssh-key`)

  ```
  ssh server1-user-name@server1.net -i /path/to/.ssh/server-1-ssh-key
  ```
- then I log in to a server with the following IP 10.0.0.10. To do this I use the key (`/home/server1-user-name/.ssh/server2-ssh-key`), which is stored on server-1

How should the ssh configuration look like for this case on my local machine?

I tried the following configuration:

```
Host server2
  Hostname 10.0.0.10
  User server2-user-name
  ForwardAgent yes
  ProxyCommand ssh -i /path/to/.ssh/server-1-ssh-key -W %h:%p
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So basically you want server1 to act as your jumpbox, so you need one stanza for server1:

```
Host server1
Hostname server1.net
User server1-user-name
IdentityFile /path/to/.ssh/server-1-ssh-key
```

Then you need a stanza for server 2 that jumps through this one:

```
Host server2
Hostname 10.0.0.10
User server2-user-name
ForwardAgent yes
ProxyCommand ssh server1 nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
IdentityFile /home/server1-user-name/.ssh/server2-ssh-key
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set AllowAgentForwarding on your both your servers' sshd_config files. You may also need to set ForwardAgent in the client config on server 1.

See: https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding